# I made a basic calculator using class and format function in python giving no error also not running

Tags: python, class, format, calculator

What changes can be done so that I can print user friendly output using one print statement only ..... It would be helpful if format can help but right now no output is coming.....

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self,a,b): # we can pass other parameters also in the constructor for assigning values
        self.a=(int)(input("Enter a"))
        self.b=(int)(input("Enter b"))

    def add(self):
        return self.a+self.b

    def sub(self):
        return self.a-self.b

    def mult(self):
        return self.a*self.b

    def div(self):
        return self.a/self.b

    def calculator(self):
        print("""sum of {0} and {1}= {} 
             subtraction of {0} and {1}={}
             Multiplication of {0} and {1}={}
             Division of {0} and {1}={}""".format(c1.a,c1.b,c1.add(),c1.sub(),c1.mult(),c1.div()))
        

c1=Calc()
c1.calculator()
```

Comment: as an aside `(int)(input("Enter a"))` is a very strange way of writing `int(input("Enter a"))`... why the strange, unecessary parentheses around `int`, i.e. why `(int)`?

Comment: No output?? Not even an error?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Class init-ing is `def __init__(self)`, not `def init(self)` (two underscores _ on both sides).</strike>

Also, you don't need `__init__(self, a, b)`, since you ask for `a` and `b` from the user anyway.

```
def __init__(self): 
    self.a = (int)(input("Enter A: ")) 
    self.b = (int)(input("Enter B: "))
```

What you might not really need to look into right now, considering the level of this code, but should for the future, is checking whether the user input can be int. Otherwise it throws errors and doesn't work anyway.

Didn't realize the underscores were already there even after I myself reformatted the question's code part.

In any case, if You really want to do this this way, you need to

1. Either add arguments when instancing `Calc()` or remove the parameters:

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

c1 = Calc()
# Next one does NOT work
c3 = Calc(var1) # Too many arguments given
```

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        ...

c1 = Calc(var1, var2)
# Next one does NOT work
c2 = Calc() # Too few arguments given
```

You can't create a new object of a class without matching its `__init__()` parameters unless the parameters are optional as such

```
class Ob:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        ...

c1 = Ob(var1) # a=var1, b=None
c2 = Ob(b=var2) # a=None, b=var2
c3 = Ob(var1, var2) # a=var1, b=var2
```

2. Formatting strings with this method You either have to use automatic field numbering or manual field specification:

```
# This does NOT work:
print("Sum of {0} and {1}= {}".format(self.a, self.b, self.add()))

# This one DOES work:
print("Sum of {0} and {1}= {2}".format(self.a, self.b, self.add()))

#This one also works:
print("Sum of {} and {}= {}".format(self.a, self.b, self.add()))
```

And as stated by @wovano, having `input()` in object initialization is bad practice alltogether. It'd be better, in Your code's case, to have an empty `__init__()` and separate function to call `input()`

```
def __init__(self):
    pass

def ask_input(self):
    self.a = (int)(input("Enter A: "))
    self.b = (int)(input("Enter B: "))
```

Comment: Your comment about `__init__()` doesn't make sense, since the code in the question already contains underscores, it was just not formatted correctly. Regarding your second point: it makes much more sense to keep the `a` and `b` parameters and move the calls to `input()` outside the `__init__()` function. It's a bad programming practice for an initializer to have side effects like this.

Comment: @wovano I don't really get how keeping `a` and `b` in `init` makes sense if the code never uses them and assigns new values based on user input anyway. In any case I found other problems with this code, which seem more likely to have been the culprits.

Comment: It's a bit of a hypothetical issue since the code in the example is so small that isn't even needed to have class members at all. But in general, you would first ask the user for values `a` and `b` and then call `Calc(a, b).calculator()`. Inside `__init_(self, a, b)` you would just store the supplied variables using `self.a = a` and `self.b = b`.

Comment: In your last example, `ask_input()` sets the class members `a` and `b`, which were not initialized in `__init__()`. Although that's entirely possible and working in Python, it's also a bad practice and `pylint` would raise a warning about it.

Comment: For a more complicated (and realistic) use case, if you would want to create unittests for the `add()`, `sub()`, `mult()` and `div()` methods, how would you do that? You would have to call `ask_input()` to define the values a and b, which means that you have to supply user input each time you run the test, and the test would give different results each time, depending on your input. If you pass a and b to the object in `__init__()`, you could easily test the whole code leaving out the user input part.